# Reducing PDF loading times using pdf.js

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

Is there anyway to reduce pdf.js (http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) loading time when opening a PDF? I am dealing with large PDF files (50MB+) and my users typically have slow networks. Sometimes it takes  2+ minutes for them to even get to the first page. Is this a limitation of the PDF format? Is it the case that in order to parse a PDF file you need to read the whole file?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your pdfs linearized? If they are not, **any** PDF viewer will have to download the whole file before displaying anything. If they are, you can look for alternative viewing plugins.

Comment: I am not sure if they are linearized, I contacted the developers working on the mozilla pdf.js project, it seems they will add some support for this.

Comment: The support for progressive loading mentioned in your answer can reduce loading times. But there always are difficult cases requiring to loaf Missy of the PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted the group working on the mozilla pdf.js project and it looks like they are working on adding support for this. For more info: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/2719

Answer (score 2):

I've done quite a lot of looking into this problem as I was writing an app that allowed customers to upload their own PDFs and then display them. Obviously this gives very little control over the size or content of the PDFs (some are more complex than others).

PDFJS offers two ways of rendering - canvas and svg, and I tried both methods. Canvas really needed to me to focus on just loading a few pages at once. If I tried anything more than that and I would often run out of canvas memory on the iPad app. Canvases take up a lot of memory whatever you do and grabbing loads of memory just slows everything down increasing load times and slowing down interactions within the viewer. SVG mode worked better at first, but due to the number of SVG elements that needed creating it was slow to scroll and meant you'd often see a clear lag in scrolling.

Based on Thomas's suggestion I looked into loading each page into a canvas, saving the canvas as a jpeg and then displaying the jpeg. This meant I only ever needed one single canvas. As my app needed a method to zoom in and out, I also had to deal with reloading pages (just on zoom in though as having a high-def jpeg on zoom out isn't too much of a problem). It created a method that not only loaded very quickly - the canvas is reused each time and each page is looped through and loaded, but it also scrolls and interacts very quickly. The challenge was getting annotations (e.g. links) to work.

What I've done is wrapped up the work that I did into an Open Source package to save others a job I hope. It does load all of the pages in, but one at a time and creates a jpeg for each page which is displayed. Usually it will work out what the current page is and re-render from there if needed. Hopefully it will be of some use to people with this problem in the future.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fast-scroll-pdf

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising).

Comment: Apologies. Wasn't my intention. After browsing these answers on here a while ago when I had the same issues I realised that there wasn't a 'solution' as such without a lot of work, so I thought I'd put the work in and then share it. Wasn't my intention to spam and apologies if it came across that way. Kinda excited as it's my first open source project that I've released so maybe went a bit too excited ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-rendering PDF pages server side and making them available as static images lets you eagerly pull in the currently viewed page at the speed of loading a single image. This can be done before the client has even loaded the PDF.js javascript and before requesting the PDF. You can follow by delegating text and richer content generation to PDF.js when it loads and processes the PDF.

You would likely need to implement your own web viewer which PDF.js provides examples of here: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/